# Android. How to set wallpaper by sending intent

Tags: android, android-intent, wallpaper

I want to call activity, where user can choose area of picture and set it as wallpaper

I have some problem with it. My code is:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmap);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

but when I choose set as wallpaper, gallery is stop working (Android 2.3), or (Android 4.0) "set as" menu doesn't displayed.

Android 2.3 LogCat (this errors in com.cooliris.media package):

```
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:2593)
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:953)
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
12-13 16:20:27.509: E/AndroidRuntime(14414):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 16:20:27.529: W/ActivityManager(225):   Force finishing activity com.cooliris.media/.Photographs
```

Android 4.0 LogCat

```
12-13 11:26:44.722: E/JavaBinder(12822): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Is there a stack trace in logcat?

Comment: so ? any answer ? @AlexanderLucas